# How to access property of a component from <script>?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I have a `<Field>` component (from Vee Validate if that matters), that has `field` and `handleChange` properties I can pass through v-slots.
The line where I call it is the following:
`<Field v-slot="{ field, handleChange }" :name="name" :value="veeValue">`

The `field` property is the one that holds the values my component will pass on submit (along with other internal VeeValidate data).
Sometimes, I receive values from the parent component that I would need to append to `field.values` in order to pass them later on submit.

I thought of:

1. gain access to `field` inside my `<script>` section (but how ?...), then setting my new values inside a watcher that will detect new values were passed from parent.
2. from inside my `<Field>` component, call a function that will trigger whenever new values were passed from parent. I will then have access to `field`.
   But I could not find any way to make these ideas work.

Are there any ways of doing that? I do not care how, I just want it to work.

Comment: it's not clear completely what you want to achieve, could you prepare a minimum reproducible example at [vue playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#eNp9kUFLwzAUx7/KM5cqzBXZbXQDlYF6UFHBSy6je+sy0yQkL3NQ+t19SdncYezW9//9X/pL24l758a7iGIqqlB75QgCUnRzaVTrrCfowOMaelh720LB1UIaaWprAkEbGpglfl08odYWvq3Xq6viRpqqHI7jg3ggbJ1eEvIEUG3u5l2Xl/u+KnnKqTIuEuxuW7tCPZOCuRRQMqzKk30xEhT49WvVjLfBGjbv0r4UtW2d0ujfHCnWk2IKmSS2ZLvfl5yRjzg65PUG658z+TbsUybFu8eAfodSHBktfYM04MXnK+75+QjZPmpuX4AfGKyOyXGoPUSzYu2TXrZ9zt9fmeYrLPaEJhwulURTs899KfifPF64+r/uZDzJe9L0ov8DExSnNA==)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Vue SFC Playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#eNp9UstOwzAQ/BXLHFokSA7cihvxEAc4AAJumENItsXg2JYfoSjKv7O2aalQ6cnendn17HoGem5M0QegM8pcY4XxxIEPpuJKdEZbTwZiYUFGsrC6IxOkTk432KXuzA9QlDGIrSLeaOU8WQiQLZnHBtPDTdZYvfrCLJ7GkXlFBq5I5hZ9LQOssSLlsG7kiitWZn2oDAMPnZG1B4xYUnEw53RIBSOnFcuP9MevQrXbSFkNP/eRJcWxQSv6ir0G77UiZ40UzQeWbAlyhQnubTpJweQQ+5+3LUkRK3NdxcrYJcrckkaPqHc49UIsi3enFW45Dctpg08LCfbOeIFb4XSW1xCxWkr9eZNy3gY4WuebN2g+duTf3SrmOL234MD2wOkG87Vdgs/w1eMtrPC+ATvdBonsPeADOC1D1JhpF0G1KHuLl9ReJz8ItXxyVysPyq2HikIjc0x8TtEfcev/jf4r96Q4SXX4+7jFtbf22NRC3XjRwx+n/nViJk2H/LGz55cxOvNfcxGS3JH1MSe132mqRNzpgPEboEgnvA==)

You can make a fake functional component to access `field` as its prop:

```
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';
import Comp from './Comp.vue';
const field = ref();
const proxy = props => {
  field.value = props.field;
}

</script>

<template>
<Comp #="{field}"><proxy v-bind="{field}"/>{{field}}</Comp>
<div><button @click="field.values.push('value')">Add value</button></div>
</template>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.
Does this technique have a name ? I would like to find some doc about it.

Comment: @LéonardKrief unfortunately i haven't encountered an official name for that. for me it's just extracting a slot's props to an external ref